# Should createContextualFragment() be able to handle xml declarations?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

Parsing a well-formed XML document that starts with an XML declaration works fine with DOMParser, but createContextualFragment throws an exception and claims `SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified`. Is this a bug in the implementation or am I missing something?

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm6649xh/) for an example.